# Odd Laurent Series

Tags: laurent-series

So, I've been studying Laurent series, and I'm fine with series such as $ \frac {1}{(z-1)(z+1)} $ for example.  For these, we can just use partial fraction decomposition and then geometric series.  However, I'm not even sure how to get started with the following function:

$ f(z)= (z^2+4)^\frac {1}{3}$

Obviously, I can see that there are zero's at $ +/- 2i $, but I have no idea how to even start to arrange this as a Laurent series.  Do I do the same thing I would do for Taylor series?  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Laurent series is related to a particular ring / annulus of convergence, which one do you want? Anyway, you need the [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) for this one.

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out which annulus it converges in.  Alright, if I use the binomial series (I'll work it out), how does that make it a Laurent series?  Feels like that's what I would do for a Taylor series.

Comment: Ahhhhh......so, |z|<2 is for a taylor series, and |z|>2 is for a Laurent series?  Would I have to factor it out somehow such that I have 1/z in the function to end up with a Laurent series?

Comment: The Taylor series is a special case of Laurent series. [See example here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series#Convergent_Laurent_series). But I spoke in haste: there isn't a Laurent series for $|z|>2$, because $f$ is multivalued there, and does not admit a holomorphic branch.

Comment: If I'm thinking of it correctly, the laurent series is no different from the taylor series in this case, correct? (seems very odd to me)

Comment: Yes. Nothing odd. The Laurent series of $e^z$ is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n/n!$, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $f(z) = \sqrt[3]{4} (({z \over 2})^2+1)^{1 \over 3}$, and use the binomial theorem to expand, this gives the Laurent series for $|z| < 2$.

Comment: Isn't that just a Taylor series though?....

Comment: It is, but it is also the Laurent series...

Comment: Hmmmmm, I'm just having trouble differentiating between the two series.  Could you please explain the difference?  I thought that laurent series had to go from -infinity to infinity?

Comment: The Taylor series only has $a_n$ for $n \ge 0$. Or think of it as $a_n = 0$ for $n < 0$. The Laurent & Taylor series are unique within the annulus or radius of convergence respectively.

Comment: Hmmmm, well, we end up only with $n>=0$, correct?  So the laurent series is just a taylor series for this example.

Comment: In this case, the Laurent series is also a Taylor series...

Comment: If a function has a Taylor series, then this is also the Laurent series for the function...

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for clarifying this for me.  Sorry about that; I don't have any resources which explain this; they just provide a standard defintion without sufficient examples.  Thanks for clarifying though.

Comment: One last question: Would it be possible to define the series in a region other than |z|<2?

Comment: A Laurent series does not exist for $|z| \ge 2$ as $f$ is multivalued there...

Comment: So, I did some more reading/digging around, and I noticed that the coefficients for the (z-zo)^(-n) terms correspond to singularity points.  Thus, since my function has no singularities, it only has coefficients ao, a1,...,an.  So, if a function has no singularities, the Laurent expansion will be equivalent to the Taylor series expansion, correct?

Comment: If a function is analytic on some disc, then the Laurent and Taylor series will be the same.